# Reset Display settings

Tags: kubuntu, display

I was trying to set up my laptop to plug into an external lcd display in portrait mode. I found an option with a visual display of the screen and a rotate button among, I believe display settings or some other related name under hardware in system settings. Unfortunately it had the undesired effect of permanently forcing my laptop to not display anything to the screen. It loads into the boot screen fine, but if I try to login to my account, it loads the display settings and then stop's displaying. I can login to the guest account fine. How do I change the settings on my actual login from either the guest account, or without being able to see anything?

**Update:** Scratch that below, that only works temporarily until I restart the computer again. Then it goes back to not displaying anything upon boot up.

Comment: no effect unfortunately. I'm using the KDE plasma workspace.

Answer (score 1):

Solved the problem via recovery mode and dpkg system repair. Apparently the display module was actually corrupted when changing the settings.